# what need to be fixed in a contigency table

Tags: case-cohort

I am little bit confused as to what entry (i.e. the "total") are fixed in a contingency table in cohort study and case-control study.

I was reading somewhere that different "total" are considered as "fixed" in a contingency table depending on whether your data is from a cohort study or a case-control study. But I don't quite understand that and what is the implication of the different assumption of which totals are fixed.

Could someone explain a bit as to what it means by "row total is fixed" or "column total is fixed" and the implication of row total being fixed instead of column total being fixed. And what inference are they trying to draw (i.e. what parameter values) by fixing the row total or column totals?

thank you